# How to fetch LinkedIn data to my CRM (Dynamics 365)?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, microsoft-dynamics, crm, dynamics-365

I have a Candidate Entity in my CRM, when I press a button i should Fetch Data from LinkedIn and populate fields in my Form (It's good to specify that I am not working with standard Web Application, I need to get the data to my CRM system)

To solve the problem:

- Create Button with Ribbon Workbench (Completed)
- Create A Script and link it with the button (Completed)
- Create a form for the fetched data to be stored in (Completed)
- Fetch Profiles Name, Surname, Position, City....

  1. Call the LinkedIn API (which I tried with LinkedIn Developer and Postman, but does not work, because I need to get the profile dynamically with different token for different LinkedIn Profiles)
  2. Try to somehow get the data from the popup window

Any ideas how to do this ?